# Sort floating point numbers in a 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, c, sorting

I came across `std:sort` but it wouldn't work in my case. I have a 2D float array wherein I need to sort just one column. Any sorting algo for FLOATS will do. I was thinking of Merge Sort, though. Anybody?

```
void selectionSort(float x[], int n) {
float curr = 0, min = 0, i = 0, temp;

for (curr = 0; curr < n-1; curr++) {
    min = curr;  // assume this is smallest

    //--- Look over remaining elements to find smallest.
    for (i = curr+1; i < n; i++) {
        if (x[i] < x[min]) {
            //--- Remember index for latter swap.
            min = i;
        }
    }

    //--- Swap smallest remaining element
    temp = x[curr];
    x[curr] = x[min];
    x[min] = temp;
}}
```

VS 2010 outputs an error: subscript is not of integral type

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @JackManey I have edited a integer sorting fxn but it wouldn't work for float. Please check my updated question. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try learning C++ first?  Rather than just copying some code, making some minor modifications, and hoping it works?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley sorry, I was working on C first then converting it later.

Comment: Well did you try learning C first then?  Because if you did, that error message would be crystal clear to you.

Comment: What, exactly, do you think "not of integral type" means?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yeah but I was asking because every code I encounter in the internet compares the iterator (which is an int) to the float numbers I wanted to sort...

Comment: @Masochist - Don't worry about code on the internet. Worry about what you're trying to do. Throw away the code that you copied and pasted and start over. **Think** through what you want to do.

Comment: Here's a hint: The code, when used to sort ints, can get away with a single declaration statement for all the variables, because it's okay if they are all the same type (int).  If you change the algorithm to sort floats, you don't have that luxury, all the variables cannot be the same type.

Comment: BTW, this code doesn't work with 2D array and doesn't sort one column.

Comment: @borisbn Yup! I will modify that later.

Answer (score 2):

C/C++ does not allow real data-types (`float`, `double` etc) as subscript operator to declare size of an array, or to access. Following is an error:

```
int ArraySize[10.0];
```

And so the following:

```
ArraySize[4.0];
```

You must pass an integral type (`int`, `long`, `char`, `bool`, `unsigned` etc) to specify the size and to access the element. If the variable is of real type, you can typecast it to int (Or, more preferably `size_t`)

```
float nIndex = 5.0; 
ArraySize[(size_t)nIndex];
```

If you have a class, then you can overload subscript operator with any type you like!